# Agregar dos ID al método .on() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo duda de si podría agregar dos id a mi método .on() para que si cambia uno o el otro ejecute la función lo estoy tratando de hacer asi:

```
   $(".formularioVenta").on("change","input#nuevoValorTarjeta","input#nuevoValorEfectivo",function(){

       var efectivo = Number($('#nuevoValorEfectivo').val());
       var tarjeta = Number($('#nuevoValorTarjeta').val());
       var total = Number($('#nuevoTotalVenta').val());
      
       var cambio = Number(efectivo) - Number(total);
       var cambio2 = Number(tarjeta) - Number(cambio);
       console.log(cambio2);

   })
```

Comment: Y porque no pones el código de la función aparte y se la asignas a cada input por aparte?

Answer (score 2):

para apuntar a dos ID los separas con comas, al ser únicos no hace falta la clase del contenedor ( form? padre? ).

```
$("input#nuevoValorTarjeta, input#nuevoValorEfectivo")
```

```js
$("input#nuevoValorTarjeta, input#nuevoValorEfectivo")
  .on("change", function() {
    var efectivo = Number($('#nuevoValorEfectivo').val());
    var tarjeta = Number($('#nuevoValorTarjeta').val());
    var total = Number($('#nuevoTotalVenta').val());

    var cambio = Number(efectivo) - Number(total);
    var cambio2 = Number(tarjeta) - Number(cambio);
    console.log({
      efectivo: efectivo,
      tarjeta: tarjeta,
      total: total,
      cambio: cambio,
      cambio2: cambio2
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=formularioVenta>
  <input type=number id=nuevoValorTarjeta placeholder="nuevoValorTarjeta" value=100 />
  <input type=number id=nuevoValorEfectivo placeholder="nuevoValorEfectivo" value=200 />
  <input type=number id=nuevoTotalVenta placeholder="nuevoTotalVenta" value=300 />
  <input id=otroInput placeholder="otroInput" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo ideal sería detectar cuando cualquier input con la clase por ejemplo: **.input** tenga un cambio haces tu funcionalidad, por ejemplo:

```
$(".input").change(function() {
});
```

Así puedes trabajar con todos los input que quieras, saludos.

Comment: Si te ha servido no olvides marcar la respuesta como la solución. Saludos